# java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ) OR

Tags: sql, exception, db2

I am facing SQL exception while running below query in db2 database.

```
UPDATE TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API
  SET     ACTION_CODE           = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_TXN_CMD,
          NEW_FACTORY_NAME      = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_SHIP_TO_CD,
          OLD_OPERATION         = '' '',
          NEW_OPERATION         = '' '',
          NEW_TXN_QTY           = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_TXN_QTY2,
          TRANSFER_FACTORY_NAME = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_TRANSFER_FACTORY_NAME,
          SUBINV_CODE           = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_SUBINV_CODE,
          TRANSFER_SUBINV_CODE  = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000_TMDV_TRANSFER_SUBINV_CODE,
          NEW_BOM_LEVEL         = '' DBK '',
          NEW_UOM_CODE          = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.UOM
Where      TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.ACTION_CODE Is null
  And     ((TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.OLD_STATE_ID = '18' And     
            TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.NEW_OPERATION = '4000' And     
            TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.OLD_OPERATION = '4000' And     
            TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.COMMENTS = 'SHIP')
   Or      (TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.OLD_STATE_ID = '19'
            And      TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.NEW_OPERATION = '4000'
            And      TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.COMMENTS = 'RECV')
            )
  And      TRINITI.T_PARENT_LOTS_API.TRANSACTION_ID = TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000.CONTROL_NO
```

Not getting where query went wrong.

Comment: What Db2 version and platform?

Comment: Why are some quotes doubled ('' DBK '') and some not (any in the where clause), your query uses a TXN_CODE19_18_FROP4000_TO4000 object that has not been that is not in any from clause

Comment: In addition to the error above. The `'' ''` sequence is not allowed in a statement. What's this? If it's a single space, then it must be `' '`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL0104N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0104n) is a syntax error. It says it is expecting another ")" somewhere. Looking at your statement, count how many "(" you open and how many closing ")" you have. That seems correct. Now, because Db2 complains about end of statement, you need to check if the statement is really passed to Db2 as given above.

Is there an additional character or formatting that indicates "end of statement"?